# Azure - OMS - East US Datacenter - Deploying Updates

Tags: azure, oms

I've setup OMS within the East US Datacenter and now I want to use the Deploying Microsoft Updates feature.  One of the prerequisites is to setup an automation account. unfortunately I don't see the option to do within the East US Datacenter to support this solution.

Is the Microsoft Update Deployment solution within OMS supported within the East US Datacenter?  I don't see this feature listed within the Azure Products by Region site.  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/regions/services/

Thanks!
-Matt

Answer (score 0):

Azure Automation, which is a requirement for this, is not available on East US Region, however I don't believe you need your automation account to be in the same region as OMS, so you can setup an automation account in say Easy US 2 where it is supported.